# WP function duplicating body content

Tags: customization

I'm trying to insert content after the `<body>` tag using my plugin but the code I have is duplicating the `<body>` content.

My code is at http://pastebin.com/rhDX8gsm (it's quite long) and the demo URL is http://bit.ly/1mRwyKY

```
function somefunction() {
    if(!is_admin()){
        global $something;
        if($something['switch-on'] == '1') {
            if($something['multipanel-on'] == '0' && $something['menu-on'] == '0'){
                $insert .=  '<div id="div1">something here</div>';
            }

            if($something['multipanel-on'] == '1') {
                $insert .=  '<div id="div2">';
                $insert .= '<ul class="carousel_buttons">';
                $insert .= '<li><a href="#" id="carousel_prev"></a></li>';
                $insert .= '<li><a href="#" id="carousel_next"></a></li>'; 
                $insert .= '</ul>';   
                $insert .= '</div>';
            }

            if($something['menu-on'] == '1') {
                $insert .= '<div id="div3">';
                $insert .= '<ul class="panel_list">';
                $insert .= '<li>';
                $insert .= '<a href="' . $url . '">';
                $insert .= '<i '.$class1.'></i>';
                $insert .= $menupost->post_title;
                $insert .= '</a>';
                $insert .= '</li>';
                $insert .= '</ul>';    
                $insert .= '</div>';
            }

            $content = ob_get_clean();
            $content .= preg_replace('#<body([^>]*)>#i',"<body$1>{$insert}",$content);
            echo $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed to use wp_footer action but not printing the code:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'somefunction',100);
function somefunction() {
    if(!is_admin()){
        global $something;
        if($something['switch-on'] == '1') {
            if($something['multipanel-on'] == '0' && $something['menu-on'] == '0'){
                $insert .=  '<div id="div1">something here</div>';
            }

            if($something['multipanel-on'] == '1') {
                $insert .=  '<div id="div2">';
                $insert .= '<ul class="carousel_buttons">';
                $insert .= '<li><a href="#" id="carousel_prev"></a></li>';
                $insert .= '<li><a href="#" id="carousel_next"></a></li>'; 
                $insert .= '</ul>';   
                $insert .= '</div>';
            }

            if($something['menu-on'] == '1') {
                $insert .= '<div id="div3">';
                $insert .= '<ul class="panel_list">';
                $insert .= '<li>';
                $insert .= '<a href="' . $url . '">';
                $insert .= '<i '.$class1.'></i>';
                $insert .= $menupost->post_title;
                $insert .= '</a>';
                $insert .= '</li>';
                $insert .= '</ul>';    
                $insert .= '</div>';
            }

            return $insert;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested all the if elses and they work (display 0 or 1 when turned on, so think it's an issue with my $insert not being sent to the footer (no code shows in the html), check the demo link at the top to see.

Comment: Please paste your code into the post for both ease of reference and longevity. If it's not all relevant, remove what you can.

Comment: Anyone able to help? :)

Comment: Where exactly do you need to insert this extra content and what is its purpose. Can't you make use of `loop_start` or `loop_end` if you need to add content before or after the loop

Comment: It needs to be in the body before or after anything else, basically it's a pull out content area is hidden off screen until you click a button, I just had a brain wave of adding to wp_footer as it's called before the end body tag

Comment: I had the same idea, but thought `loop_end` would be a better choice as it is called after the loop has ended, so anything added here will be after the loop, and usually before the footer

Comment: But depending on the theme could include loads of HTML which could react with the code I am trying to insert, will see how I get on with this footer idea.

Comment: You should post a solution if you come up with one. Always nice to see how the solution looks like, and it also keeps a question constructive. Good luck. I hope you solve this soon. :-)

Comment: Changed the function action to wp_footer but it's not printing the code out (demo updated), can anyone see a reason for it not working?

Comment: Give your methods and variables meaningful names. I stopped reading when a function was named `someFunction` and a variable `$something` soon after. Horrific coding practice.

Comment: That's not how it's in my code on the site, it's just what I have converted to for showing the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, wasn't the code but the actual IF elses, I had moved the panel it's built on from SMOF to Redux but SMOF gives the input a 0 if set to x, but redux leaves it blank, so I was basically checking if the input was 0 and it was failing, hence no content being sent.

tip for future, read the documentation a bit more.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a new filter expression immediately after the `<body>` tag. Like the following

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php echo apply_filters("immediately_after_body","");?>
```

Now in your functions.php add the filter hook like this

```
add_filter("immediately_after_body","my_function");
function my_function(){
    //do your calculation
    return "<h1>output from Filter Hook</h1>";
}
```

You can see the output immediately after `<body>` tag. Use filters, they were built for a purpose :)

Comment: yes or use a custom *action* hook via `do_action`.

Comment: theoretically when you're dealing with contents and modifying it then filters are preferred.

think of actions like event listeners instead :)

Comment: I can't as it's being used in a plugin, is there a way to add the function to jQuery and use prependTo?

Comment: @HasinHayder, yes sure, I was just thinking about the  `wp_head/wp_footer`  similarities ;-)